# Is $f(x) = e^x - e^{-x}$ invertible on $\Bbb R$?

Tags: functions

Consider the function $f : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ defined by

$$ f(x) = \exp(x)-\exp(-x)$$

Is $f$ an invertible function? Give reasons for your answer.

The answer given with this question states that since the function is continuous, it is surjective and since it is increasing, it is injective and so bijective and hence invertible. But is it true that all continuous functions are surjective and if this reason is correct?

Comment: Not all continuous functions are surjective, e.g. constants.

Comment: Then by what reasoning is this function invertible?

Comment: Increasing implies injective implies invertible.  That is the entire argument (though it does need to be made rigorous).  Surjectivity has nothing to do with invertibility.

Answer (score 1):

This amounts to solving the equation that $u=e^{x}-e^{-x}$ for a given $u\in{\bf{R}}$ for a unique solution. Let $v=e^{x}$, then $u=v-v^{-1}$, so $v^{2}-uv-1=0$, and the discriminant is $u^{2}+4>0$, we have two roots $v_{1}=\dfrac{u+\sqrt{u^{2}+4}}{2}$ and $v_{2}=\dfrac{u-\sqrt{u^{2}+4}}{2}$, pick the positive one $v_{1}$ because $e^{x}>0$. Because $e^{x}$ is bijective, then there is a unique $x$ that $e^{x}=v_{1}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is an odd strictly increasing function (compute $f'$) that is bounded neither above nor below.  It is therefore invertible.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative $e^x+e^{-x}$ never cancels, hence the function is strictly increasing. And being the sum of two continuous functions, it is also continuous.